# using a Spanish pretrained model with Gensim causes raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)

Tags: python, deep-learning, gensim, word-embedding, keyerror

I am struggling with the following problem:

I downloaded a **pre-trained word embedding model** for **Spanish** (over 1 million words 300-dimensional word vectors for Spanish)
I loaded it successfully and I even managed to undertake a couple of experiments, such as most similar words and basic analogies in Spanish (A is to B as C is to what), but when I try the following:

```
 for pais in 'Italia', 'Francia', 'India', 'China':
      print(' is the capital of '  
      (A_is_to_B_as_C_is_to('Alemania','Berlín',pais),pais))
```

It raises the error:

```
KeyError: "word 'Berlín' not in vocabulary"
```

I already checked that the word is actually in the word embedding. I have also eliminated the possibility of an encoding error.

Based on my research, this type of error is produced when the token/word is supposed to be wrapped in a list [], however I don’t know how to apply that to this specific problem. Besides, this block of code is the same code used in “**Deep Learning Cookbook**” in chapter 3 (Word2vecMath)

This is the complete script:

```
import os
from keras.utils import get_file
import gensim

from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

import subprocess
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize


from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import json
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

from keras.models import load_model
path = ("D:\Pretrained_wordEmbeddings_ESP\embeddings-l-model.vec")


model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(path, binary=False)


data=model.most_similar(positive=["muerte"])

print(data[:])


def A_is_to_B_as_C_is_to(a, b, c, topn=1):
    a, b, c = map(lambda x:x if type(x) == list else [x], (a, b, c))
    res = model.most_similar(positive=b + c, negative=a, topn=topn)
    if len(res):
        if topn == 1:
            return res[0][0]
        return [x[0] for x in res]
    return None

A_is_to_B_as_C_is_to('hombre', 'mujer', 'rey')

## for pais in 'Italia', 'Francia', 'India', 'China':
##    print(' is the capital of '  
##          (A_is_to_B_as_C_is_to('Alemania', 'Berlín', pais), pais))
```

Thank you from your support

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error like `KeyError: "word 'Berlín' not in vocabulary"`, then you can trust that error: the word really isn't in the vocabulary. (It's not due to a lack of specifying it inside a list.)

You can check this directly via code like...

```py
print(model['Berlín'])
```

...which will likely display the same error.

If you believe you've "already checked that the word is actually in the word embedding", please edit your question to show the check you performed, in code and output, to verify its presence.

You can view the words actually in the model inside the list `model.index2entity`. For example, you could display the 1st 10 words in the model via:

```py
model.index2entity[:10]
```

...or look for the position in that list of a word via...

```py
model.index2entity.index('Berlín')
```

But, for a word-not-present, you'll get a `ValueError`.

I do note you've quoted the word with the Spanish-language letter `í` ([i-acute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8D#Portuguese,_Spanish)) rather than the plain dotted-i `i` letter used in other alphabets.

Depending on how the word-vectors were constructed, perhaps the word is available in an de-accented form (`'Berlin'`), or a case-flattened form (`'berlín'`), or both (`'berlin'`), or not at all.

If not at all, then you'd want to check for its availability before trying to use it in analogy-solving code, or set up a `try: ... except: ...` error-catching construct to handle the error whenever it comes up.

Comment: The word embedding was lower_cased. So, my initial post was inaccurate, the words berlín and berlin were actually in the word embedding which (now I know) does not entail Berlin or Berlín are also included.